# find_all with multiple attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, findall

I want to find **all** the links on the page, this code is only getting the links which starts with `http://`, however most of the links are `https://` how can I edit thee code below to find both?

```
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href':re.compile("^http://")}):

import requests,bs4,re
res=requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/21/nyregion/president-trump-immigration-law-firms.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage')
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
for link in soup.find_all('a',attrs={'href':re.compile("^http://")}):
    print(link.get('href'))
    x=link.get('href')
```

I know I can simply do to get all the links but I wanted to get both `http://`and `https://` in one `find_all`

```
for i in soup.select('a'):
    print(i.get('href'))
```

Comment: how about using this regexp `^(http|https)://.*` . ?

Comment: or  use `^http*://[a-zA-z]`

Comment: If you want to find all links, why are you filtering the attributes at all?

Comment: @Barmar the links comes with their text and font formats and stuff like that

Comment: @Enix your edit works, you can post as answer if you want

Comment: @timmy glad to hear that... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regular expression to match `http` or `https`:

```
^(http|https)://.*
```

Regular expression `(a|b)` means : match pattern `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 0):

you want to categorize your link into http and https? find it using `.startswith()` or `re.match()`

```
http = []
https = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = link.get('href')
    if url.startswith('http://'): # or: if re.match("^http://", url)
      http.append(url)
    else:
      # should be https://
      https.append(url)

print(https)
print(http)
```

Comment: this wouldn't work all the time,i think you should use elif instead of else,to remove any possible error right?

Comment: it just an example you can improve it by adding elif.